# Change Time.now on server to return different timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone

I have an app deployed on a server where the system time is 7 hours behind UTC. I'm actually in England so I want times displayed in local time GMT (with daylight saving adjusted).

A gem that I'm using, resque, uses Time.now to retrieve the current time. What do I need to configure to get Time.now to return the correct time?

Comment: I suppose you don't have the chance to just set the right time zone on your server, e.g. with `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` on a Debian machine?

Comment: I'm using dotcloud and don't have root access. Using an environment variable is good because it means I don't have to configure each server I'm using individually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set the ENV["TZ"] variable.

```
> Time.now
=> 2011-05-21 13:13:23 +0200 
> ENV["TZ"] = "Europe/London"
=> "Europe/London"
> Time.now
=> 2011-05-21 12:13:55 +0100
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out some "time warping" gems: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/time_warping.html